# What kind is this background called and where to find more?

Tags: images, background, texture

I found this background which is being used in [Wordpress Stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/):

[image: http://cdn.sstatic.net/wordpress/img/bg-watermark.png]

Link: http://cdn.sstatic.net/wordpress/img/bg-watermark.png

I don't know what kind is this background called in English: texture, footage... or what? (I'm not so good at English). I want to find more images like this to use in my project but I have no idea what keyword to use.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think it's called "pattern background"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try "gothic clipart" in a google image search, and head from there.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I want. I am finding some clipart that look "mathematic" for my math project. Do you have any suggestion for me?

Comment: try "geometric designs" or "geometric clipart".

Comment: and then try combinations of "geometric gothic clipart" that should be almost exactly what you want.